# How to dynamically adjust zoom in Heatmap.js in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, json, openlayers, heatmap

Consider the following code:

```
heatmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Heatmap( "Heatmap Layer", map, osm,
{visible: true, radius: radiusForScale[zoom], legend: {position: 'br',title: 'title'}}, 
{isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.3, projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")}
);
```

Background: heatmap.js is great for displaying population densities and such... however, I do not want heatmap.js to control the radius of my points. Instead, I wish to dynamically updated the radius based on a custom zoom function I have created, without having to destroy the heatmap and recreate it every time the zoom changes. Now, this is possible if you add the heatmap to a div as follows:

```
var config = {
    element: document.getElementById("heatmapArea"),
    radius: 30,
    opacity: 50
};

//creates and initializes the heatmap
var heatmap = h337.create(config);
```

In this example, it's as simple as updating the JSON object and updating the display. However, this in only a static display assigned to a div, and therefore renders the vector layer useless. Has anyone had any success with this in OpenLayers??

On a side note: I've browsed through all the keys in the heatmap JSON string and there doesn't seem to be a way to change the zoom variable.

Comment: NOTE:  This is NOT using the heatmap functionality of OL3. It's the library created by Patrick Wied.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out... this isn't advertised in the documentation or anywhere on the internet that I could find.. however, here's how you control the radius in OpenLayers for those of you who need it. Let's keep it simple..

```
// create our heatmap layer
var heatmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Heatmap( 
"Heatmap Layer", map, osm, {visible: true, radius:50}, 
{isBaseLayer: false, opacity: 0.3, projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")}
);
map.addLayers([heatmap]);
```

Now add the data:

```
heatmap.setDataSet(data);
```

Here's the key. You can do pretty much anything with this list of commands:

```
this.set("radius",value); //****this one solved my problem
this.set("element",value);
this.set("visible",value); //deceiving! You have to access the canvas subclass to get it to work
this.set("max",value);
this.set("gradient",value);
this.set("opacity",value);
this.set("width",value);
this.set("height",value);
this.set("debug",value);
```

So, for example, create a zoom event so the radius changes based on your radius function. For me, it was as simple as scaling the radius based on the ratio screen width(pixels)/screen width(meters). So now in your click event:

```
on zoom change: //pseudocode
canvas = heatmap.heatmap.get('canvas'); //this is the subclass I spoke of above
if the zoom is above a certain value //pseudocode
then
canvas.style.display = 'block'; //show the heatmap... you can also use heatmap.toggle() but this gives you more control
heatmap.heatmap.set('radius',zoomfunction[map.zoom]); //this dynamically updates the radius!!
heatmap.updateLayer();
else
canvas.style.display = 'none';
heatmap.updateLayer();
```

I hope this helps someone 'cause it drove me crazy!

Comment: This doesn't work. The radius doesn't change, even though it accepted the change. The problem is that the style is created when the heatmap layer is initialized. I might have to recreate the heatmap.

Comment: Are you sure you're updating the layer? This works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm updating the attributes of the heatmap layer. Looking at the code, there's no way this will work. I'm curious how this is working for you. I'll try to post a fiddle when I get a chance.

In the ol.layer.Heatmap constructor in http://ol3js.org/en/master/build/ol-whitespace.js, take a look at setStyle - the icon references a circle (search for 'src:circle') which is defined above it and there's no way to change it dynamically once the style has been defined.... any thoughts?

Comment: Nick, I hope I'm understanding you correctly. The current heatmap library dynamically adjusts the radius and the colors as you zoom in, which doesn't give you a realistic representation of certain things. For my example, I wanted to show received signal strength from a transmitter. So, my goal was to keep the colors and the radius as I zoomed in. Is this what you're trying to do?

P.S. I'm new to stackoverflow... how do I post a large amount of code beyond the character limit?  Perhaps I can just email the answer, but I'd like to share it here.

Comment: It would be nice to see what you're doing. From what I see in code, OL & Heatmap integration is quite limited. Can you post a working solution on JSFiddle? That's what is used for code sharing html/js/css mostly.

Comment: Btw, I asked this question on the thread where the author said I have to recreate the layer. So, I'm not sure why and how it works for you. Maybe you can chime in there? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/y9KZmoraSbQ

Comment: For the life of me, i can't seem to get jsFiddle to recognize heatmap.js and openlayers together. I can create a simple heatmap, and I can create a simple openlayers map. However, as soon as I combine them, it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've never used jsFiddle before. Can you create a simple example of the two working in jsFiddle? I can come in behind you and modify it so it uses my function.

Comment: Now I understand why we're talking past each other. I'm not using the OpenLayers 3 (ol.Layer.Heatmap) that's inherent in that library. I'm using heatmap.js created by Patrick Wied. I've not yet updated to OL3 nor have I ever used that heatmap before. Sorry, I just looked at the google group link and noticed it said OL3 Dev.

Comment: I figured by the end of this, lol. I always thought that it was using heatmap.js. Maybe it used code off that lib? Anyway, I wonder which approach is better. Is your code for your heatmap layer available somewhere? It would be nice to compare the two approaches. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no clue if it's using it or not. I searched for keywords in the whitespace-ol.js like "setDataSet" and found nothing similar. If I had to guess, I'd say they're not related. However, I'm not a seasoned javascript-er. My code is actually inter-twined with a larger application at my job. However, I can drum up an example for you if you know of a place I can drop it. Or, if stackoverflow allows us to somehow swap information I can just email you some examples.