# Heatmap.js with Openlayers and wfs layer: how to implement?

Tags: vector, openlayers, heatmap, layer

I'm following the heatmap.js example with openlayers to create a heatmap http://csn0.gps.caltech.edu/Events/heatmap.js-master/website/example-heatmap-openlayers-renderer.html.
My data comes from the geoserver and I search through WFS. How do I fetch wfs data with heatmap?

```
var my_layer_heatmap = new ol.layer.Vector({
    title: 'My layer',
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return urlGeoserver +'wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version='+versionGeoserver+'&request=GetFeature&typename=geo:GEO_MY_LAYER&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:4326&' +
              'all=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:4326';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all
    }),
});
```

Comment: `ol.layer.Vector` should be `ol.layer.Heatmap` https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.layer.Heatmap.html  You will need to specify a `weight` attribute or function if the source if the source does not contain one.

Comment: @Mike Hi, I managed to do it with ol.layer.Heatmap. However, I would like to use the heatmap.js file from the example http://csn0.gps.caltech.edu/Events/heatmap.js-master/website/example-heatmap-openlayers-renderer.html. I have already done it with leaflet , however, did not come the geoserver data, so I'm not getting it.

Comment: @Mike Here is an example of heatmap.js, however I would like to use the data coming from a wfs layer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548700/how-to-dynamically-adjust-zoom-in-heatmap-js-in -openlayers

Comment: Your code is OpenLayers 3 or later.  The example you linked is OpenLayers 2   The versions are not compatible,

Comment: Ah understood. Thanks. I'll use it with ol.layer.Heatmap then.